# how to query json data in text field rails postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I have a database table column(`collection`) with `data type text`

I have inserted json data in `collection`

This is my json data

```
{"name":"test","age":"25","country":"xxx"}
```

But now how do i query this json data. Is there any option as follows

```
User.where(collection: :name) # Here name denotes test
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Since JSON is a string, you can only make string comparisons using SQLite/MySQL(or any other database). Also, try to keep datatype as **binary**.

You can perform: **LIKE** operation for occurrence of sub-string inside your stored JSON string.

The above comparison you are doing will not work as it is meant for searching only name in collection column whereas you have stored a whole JSON string in that column.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider using the json datatype

https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore

You don't need this gem if you're using rails 4, but the docs still apply.